# Why isn’t it possible to create VeraCrypt containers in Tails?

Tags: tails-os, veracrypt

I know it’s possible to [read](https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/veracrypt/index.en.html) them, but not create them and `veracrypt` isn’t installed by default. Curious to know why. Duck Duck Go’d like crazy.